# Adding column manually to table in dbml file

Tags: linq-to-sql

I manually added a column to a table in a .dbml file by editing the xml.
Hereafter I rigthclicked the .dbml and chose 'Run Custom Tool'.

I'm new to linq-to-sql and is working on an existing MVC webapp with domainmodel and viewmodel.

The solution also contains a database project which I know was not updated automatically.

Now I need to know how to check that everything was updated correctly. Is it only the .dbml and the .designer.cs that I can expect to be changed after running the custom tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Run Custom Tool' does the trick. Nothing else is needed.
And no other files than .dbml and the .designer.cs files are changed.